# How to combine two dataframes by index (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, with the same `date` field, but different other fields. I need to add a column `pneumonia_ARVI` from dataframe `pneumonia_ARVI` to dataframe `Result_data`.

They initially differ in the number of dates, in `Result_data` dataframe there are significantly more dates than in `pneumonia_ARVI`

[image]

I need a concatenation with a date match, but if the records in the dataframe `pneumonia_ARVI` than in the dataframe `Result_data`, then the preference would have the dates specified in the dataset `Result_data`. And the data that is missing in the dataset `pneumonia_ARVI` replaced with empty values.

I have tried doing

```
Result_data = Result_data.set_index('date')
pneumonia_ARVI = pneumonia_ARVI.set_index('date')
End = pd.merge(Result_data, pneumonia_ARVI, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

But this led to the fact that the data was adjusted to each other, and the field `infected_city` do not leave all their original values by date.

How to combine this data correctly so that there are no problems with reducing the total number of dates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
#convert to datetime if needed
Result_data["date"] = pd.to_datetime(Result_data["date"])
pneumonia_ARVI["date"] = pd.to_datetime(pneumonia_ARVI["date"])

#set index as you have done
Result_data = Result_data.set_index('date')
pneumonia_ARVI = pneumonia_ARVI.set_index('date')

#perform a left join
End = Result_data.join(pneumonia_ARVI, how="left")
```